# Skolem Theorem in ZFC

Tags: set-theory

I have two questions about a quote from Wang ('On Denumerable Bases in Formal System' 1955, pp. 66-67). In order to give some context, I quote the entire sentence - which concerns a comparison between Hilbert's Epsilon Calculus and ZFC. However, my question concern only the part in bold letters:

> There are also cases where, although the $\varepsilon$-rules would yield the desired result, the axiom of choice would not. For example, in the Zermelo's theory we can infer '$(x)R(x, \varepsilon yRxy)'$ from '$(x)(\exists y)Rx,y$' **but we cannot infer** 'there exists *f*, $(x)R(x,fx)$' **from** '$(x)(\exists y)Rx,y$' **by the axiom of choice, on account of the absence of a**
>   **universal set in Zermelo's theory**.

1) Why so? According to my point of view, there is a tension here: on the one hand, Wang is considering an instance of the Skolem theorem (namely, the metatheorem for FOL) which is proved in ZFC. On the other hand, Wang asserts that this is not possible. Can someone clear up my confusion? 
2) Is it the case also for the (First-order) Skolem Normal Form, namely: can we infer $(x)R(x,fx)$ from $(x)(\exists y)Rx,y$ in ZFC?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited the post adding the required information, and explaining my doubts about the quote.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the issue here is some accidental carelessness with what the Skolem theorem says. What ZFC proves is that *given a model* of some theory, the Skolem functions *on that model* are sets. But the ZFC universe is not a model; it is not a set in the ZFC universe equipped with a binary relation because of Russell's paradox, so the theorem doesn't apply.

Now, this doesn't mean by itself that there is no such set that is a Skolem function on the universe, but Russell's paradox *does* mean this. For if we had a function of the sort above, it would be a set of ordered pairs $\{(x,f(x))\:|\: x\in V\}$, which is a proper class; if it were a set we could get $V$ as a set using the other axioms.